# Using delete button inside a Html table to delete the record

Tags: laravel

I have done the following:

```
<tbody style="font-family: Nunito">
  @if($users)
      @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr class="text-right">
          <th scope="row">{{$ids[$user->id]}}</th>
          <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
          <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$dates[$user->id]}}</td>
          <td class="text-left">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger px-4" style="font-family: myFirstFont" href="{{route('users.destroy', $user->id)}}">Delet</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
  @endif
</tbody>
```

When I change the parameter inside route to 'users.edit', the code inside the edit method in the controller runs.

but when I write 'users.destroy', the code inside destroy method does not run.

It does not give any error.

Comment: check the route declared for the method [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing]

Comment: laravel resource defines 'users.destroy' as DELETE method but you are using get method. You should use `<form action="{{ route(users.destroy)}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf  
</form>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<form action="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}" method="POST">   
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```